# Why are these two sums equal?

Tags: summation

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_j^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i^2 \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i^2$

I don't recall any properties that can do this. Is there a general property for this summation behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2$$

and same for $b_i$ and $b_j$. It does not matter which index you are summing over. If you want, you can call the index you are summing over "squirrel", if that's your thing.

One way of seeing this is simply writing it:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_n^2= \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2$$

Another way is to actually prove by induction (as that is the definition of the sum sign). In fact, even the squares don't count:

Let
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\\T_n = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j$$

Then, we claim that for all integers $n$, we have $S_n = T_n$.

- If $n=1$, then by definition, $S_n = S_1 = c_1$ and $T_n = T_1 = c_1$ so the statement holds.
- Assume the statement holds for $n$. Then $S_n = T_n$. We know by definition that $S_{n+1} = S_n + c_{n+1}$ and $T_{n+1} = T_n + c_{n+1}$. Because $S_n=T_n$, we know that $$S_{n+1} = S_n + c_{n+1} = T_n + c_{n+1} = T_{n+1}$$ so the induction is proven.

Comment: For completeness: The variable is called a "dummy variable" in situations like this.